# Draw rhombus inscribed in a group with circle SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have multiple `<g>` elements and all of them have a circle:

```
<g class="my-group">
    <circle r="40" cx="10" cy="10"></circle>
</g>
```

In some cases I need to draw a `rectange` with ***rounded corners*** instead of `circle`, it should be presented as rhombus. I'm trying to draw it like this:

```
<g class="my-group">
    <rect x="-16" y="-30" width="60" height="60" fill="red" transform="rotate(45)" rx="4"></rect>
</g>
```

But this is a wrong way to hardcode `coordinates` and `width`/`height` of rect.

How I can calculate `width` and `height` of rotated rect to inscribe it in circle, so group will have the same width and height `80px`.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple pythagorean theorem. Rectangle width  (or hypotenuse) equals the square root of two lots of the radius squared.

```js
const radius = document.querySelector('#circle').getAttribute('r')
const rectWidth = Math.sqrt(radius * radius * 2)
const square = document.querySelector('#square')

square.setAttribute('x', -rectWidth/2 + 'px')
square.setAttribute('y', -rectWidth/2 + 'px')
square.setAttribute('width', rectWidth + 'px')
square.setAttribute('height', rectWidth + 'px')
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle id="circle" fill="green" r="40" cx="50" cy="50"></circle>
    <rect id="square" fill="red" transform="translate(50, 50) rotate(45)"></rect></svg>
```